# Improvement request for the poorly-positioned "Welcome back!" notification

Tags: feature-request, design, notifications

It is very annoying to see the notification completely hiding the menu-bar. Whenever I open any SE website, I look at my notifications and rep changes but when the "Welcome Back!" notification appears, it hides everything on the menu-bar, so it's kinda irritating. People have disabled it through extensions etc but I suggest improving it. Here is its current image:

> [image: Current image]

---

## Here is what I am expecting:

> [image: Edited image]

Can this please be implemented on all Stack Exchange sites?

***<sub>TIP: Click on the images for higher quality view...</sub>***

Comment: This is a great idea!

Comment: I am not an html programmer, so I photoshoped it ;)

Comment: It's worth noting that the original code for the banner was implemented several years back (during the Jeff days), and that code has never been touched ever since. It incorporates elements from an older design of Stack Exchange, and the banner is similar to the old "global auth" banner (now removed and replaced with network-wide universal authentication).

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousWizHog I don't know about it, but as it is said, "With time, things change", so it must happen.

Comment: Curiously though, how often does this happen to you? I only get it like once a week.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Whenever I am looking for answers at other SE sites. Also, I am a busy person studying so I am not too active on SE for now

Comment: This Stacks design component might be used for this: https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/banners (it‘s their base design for all sites)

Comment: @catija the "welcome back" banner could well be annoying for two reasons; the fact it appears repeatedly, in the OP's case, and annoying due to its position. Judging by approval ratings, I don't think anyone was confused by the original title.